# iOS Core Bluetooth - Can't discover the real device from scan

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to discover a bluetooth device and connect to it through the use of `CBCentralManager`. The device is a headset. It can be discovered through bluetooth scan on the phone. The device name is "A1-25". When I connect "A1-25" directly from phone bluetooth settings, I can play songs with it, it's working fine.

[image]

However, when I started scanning peripherals using `CBCentralManager`. I can't see a peripheral named "A1-25". But rather, I saw a peripheral named "EQ_Test_llyan". But before, when I scan nearby devices from the bluetooth settings, "EQ_Test_llyan" did not come out.

```
2017-12-13 16:35:07.233021+0800 Test[1405:500801] started scanning
2017-12-13 16:35:17.469375+0800 Test[1405:500801] discovered peripheral with name EQ_Test_llyan advertisementData:{
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = "EQ_Test_llyan";
    kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <b0024551 5f544553 54>;
}
2017-12-13 16:35:17.470672+0800 Test[1405:500801] connecting with device!!!!!!!
2017-12-13 16:35:17.654884+0800 Test[1405:500801] connected to peripheral name:EQ_Test_llyan id:7326E741-BF68-D9E8-D7A6-5F27227685A7
2017-12-13 16:35:17.656526+0800 Test[1405:500801] discovering services for peripheral name:EQ_Test_llyan
2017-12-13 16:35:18.193311+0800 Test[1405:500801] discovered services:(
) for peripheral name:EQ_Test_llyan
```

The peripheral "EQ_Test_llyan" has no services (see above log), so I can't communicate with it. Now, when I went back to the bluetooth devices in the phone settings I am now connected to "EQ_Test_llyan", but not to "A1-25". Now, I try to play the music, the sound does not come out from the headset.

[image]

When I turned off the headset, I will be disconnected from "EQ_Test_llyan" and "A1-25" will be gone. Therefore I conclude that "EQ_Test_llyan" and "A1-25" comes from the same device.

Take note that I can connect to both at the same time. I will just connect to "EQ_Test_llyan" programmatically, then it will appear on the settings. Then I manually connect to "A1-25" from the phone settings. It will be like what it shows on the picture below. When I play the music, I can still hear sound coming out from headset. So, it's working fine as long as I am connected to "A1-25", but not to "EQ_Test_llyan" alone.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is CBPeripheral referring to the actual device? Because if it is,
   why can't I scan "A1-25" but I can scan "EQ_Test_llyan"?
2. Take note that when the phone is connected to "A1-25", it has an "i"
   beside it, this means that the connection can be terminated. But
   when the phone is connected to "EQ_Test_llyan", there's no "i"
   beside it. So, it can't be disconnected unless you turned off the
   device. So, what's the difference between the two? Is "AI-25" the
   real device, while "EQ_Test_llyan" is just a connection? I don't
   understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not discover "A1-25" from the `CBCentralManager` because it is a headset as you've mentioned. Headset uses Headset Profile (HSP), which is known as "Bluetooth Classic" profile, while Core Bluetooth is suitable only for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, Bluetooth 4.0) General Attribute Profile (GATT). If you examine the CoreBluetooth API, you'll discover it's all about services and characteristics. It has no abstractions for sound-related profiles.

On the other hand, GATT is very general and abstract profile, and can be used by a device of any kind, each time for some very specific data — speed, temperature, heart rate, some device configuration, and virtually any other values. So you can pair to GATT devices only from an app that aware of that exact device. You just have nothing to do with such generic service from your phone settings screen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. So, If that's the case, is it possible that I could still fetch the sound from the mic of the bluetooth headset and play it from the app? What I mean is, you said that there's no sound-related profiles from the BLE GATT profile right? So, does that mean I can't pass real time sound data with BLE?

Comment: You can not pass real time sound via BLE connection, it has unsuitable API and runs at too low speed to transmit sound.

You can use your headset to play and record sounds from your app. Pair the headset (A1-25) on the phone settings screen. After that you'll need to configure audio session in the app to use the headset, not internal mic and speaker.